# Bitnami Grafana-operator persistence problem

Tags: grafana, persistence, azure-aks, operator-keyword, bitnami

I am trying to deploy bitnami/grafana-operator to AKS with persistence. I want to be able to create Dashboards in UI and they to be persistent. I am using Helm chart, where the persistence.enabled is set to true. A PVC with PV are created, but when I describe the PVC it says Used By: . And deleting the pod, deletes all the Dashboards as well. How can I change that?

I want to make the grafana-operator-deployments pods persistent

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the bitnami grafana operator, I suppose that the best way to make your dashboards persistent is by using the GrafanaDashboard CRD. Did you try that?
When using the latest bitnami version there is a good example here: https://github.com/grafana-operator/grafana-operator/blob/master/docs/blog/v4-v5-migration.md
It explains how the grafana board template should look like, and where to put the dashboardLabelSelector in the grafana CRD.